# When and where object is getting created?

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm not a java expert but with a basic knowledge. I want to understand how and when the object is being created in below code.

```
org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

import java.io.IOException;
public class WordCountMapper
{
extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable>
@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
}
}
String line = value.toString();
for (String word : line.split(" ")){
if(word.length()>0){
context.write(new Text(word),new IntWritable(1));
}
```

Here is the main method class

```
package com.company;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
if(args.length !=2){
System.err.println("Invalid Command");
System.err.println("Usage: WordCount <input path> <output path>");
System.exit(0);
}
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");
job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
}
```

In map method parameter like map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) have passed and every individual parameter is an instance of the class we have imported in code on the top.

And these parameters are holding data which is further being processed into the code above. I want to know the moment we start running the above code, when and where the object creation is happening?

Is it somewhere written in Hadoop framework that, whenever the code runs it instantiates an object with the data which want to process in constructor's parameter of that class to create an object and pass this object into a map method?

May I know how this linkage is happening step by step? Or I'm thinking in wrong way? Please give me some direction to understand this.

Comment: By the time the above code runs, the objects have already been created.  I think you need to find a good beginning Java book and study it carefully.  Your thinking is so confused right now that it's impossible for us to help you here.

Comment: @ajb, I have found the entry point of code. Please check the question again, but still I would say where Text object is getting created if not in main method ?